# Why this char Array(C language) prints more than its capacity?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have this `int count[1];` this array gives me `3 Rab` output! but it has only 2 capacity and i wondered why?!

```
struct MEMBERS
{
    int code;
    char Fname[40];
    char Lname[40];
    int Pnum[20];
    float bedeh;
    float credit;
    int count[1];
    struct meroDate issued;
    struct meroDate duedate;
};
struct MEMBERS b;

int main()

{
  int i = 0, line = 5;
  char w[100];
  int str[100];
                FILE *myfile;
                myfile = fopen("Members.txt","r");
   if (myfile== NULL)
      {
         printf("can not open file \n");
         return 1;
      }

      while(line--){
                fgets(str,2,myfile);
                strncpy(b.count, str, 1);
              i++;
             printf("%s",b.count);
                   }

         fclose(myfile);

         return 0;

 }
```

my `Members.txt` contains:

```
3
Rebaz salimi 3840221821 09188888888
4
95120486525
95120482642
```

Comment: `int[]` is not a string. so, `printf("%s",b.count);` is not what you wanna use. use a for loop to print the contents of the the `int[]` one by one or use a `char*`.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is an array of integers which can hold only one element. You pass it to functions which required `char *` as arguments thus, causing undefined behaviour.

```
printf("%s",b.count);      // %s expects char * not int[]
```

Also here-

```
strncpy(b.count, str, 1);
```

You need to manually copy using loop or use [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) depending on your data.

Edit :-

```
  fgets(str,2,myfile);
        if(sscanf(str, "%d", &b.count[0])==1){
               printf("%d\n", b.count[0]);
               i++;
    }
```

read from file and store in `b.count[0]`, check return of `sscanf` if successful then print it's value.

Also,

```
fgets(str,2,myfile);
      ^^^ str is int[] but fgets requires argument as char *.
```

So `str` should be of type `char *`.

Comment: then what do u suggest me to get only number 3 as only integer to be output of  'b.count'

Comment: @moh89  What output  do you expect to get from this ? Clearly you can store only integer in integer array. For string part you need to do something else.

Comment: i need to get only first line integer and store it in 'int count[1]'